# DynDns not updating on NAS

Tags: nas, dynamic-dns

I've recently bought an LG N2R1 NAS device, and wanted to be able to access it via the web when away from home.

Anyway I've installed the latest firmware and set up the DynDns connection, and it seemed to work fine for a while.

Then a day or 2 later it stopped working, and I was at a bit of a loss as to why, I expect it was because my IP had changed and it had not updated the DynDns end to tell it the IP had changed.

Anyway im not really that clued up when it comes to this sort of stuff, so any help would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update DynDNS with your new IP each time you receive one, I can't find anywhere that suggests this NAS has that ability built in with a quick look.

You may find this* page helpful in finding an update client for your operating system which will tell DynDNS each time your IP changes (and therefore, should allow you to connect to your NAS from the internet).

Many Routers have this ability built in now, so you may wish to look there first (as it saves your PC being online in order to update your DynDNS).

- = http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/